# Mathematical expectation of a quotient of exponential von Mises-Fisher distribution

Tags: integration, statistics, spheres, density-function

I was attempting to calculate a mathematical expectation since yesterday. It seems complicate for me and i can not do it. May be someone can help me here.

Let be $u_1$ and $u_2$ two positions on a 3 dimensional unit hypersphere.
I need to calculate $$P=\int_{z}\frac{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta u_1z)}{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta u_1z)+\exp(\alpha_2 + \beta u_2z)}dF(z)$$
Suppose that $z \sim \mathcal{M}_3(\eta,v)$, that is a 3 dimensional von Mises-Fisher distribution with intensity parameter $\eta$ and mean directional parameter $v$.

In fact the answer can help me to compute for the general case which is
$$P_i=\int_z\dfrac{\exp(\alpha_i + \beta u_iz)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \exp(\alpha_i + \beta u_iz)}dF(z)$$
with $\alpha_i$, $\beta$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.
Thanks!

Comment: so the $u_k z$ means scalar product or something else?

Comment: Thank mathreadler
Yes it means scalar product